# How To customize user account creation form

Tags: theming, users

I successfully customized the user login and password reset form using this:

```
function responsive_bartik_theme() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user_login'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'responsive_bartik') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-login',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
       'responsive_bartik_preprocess_user_login'
    ),
  );
  $items['user_pass'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'responsive_bartik') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-pass',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
      'responsive_bartik_preprocess_user_pass'
    ),
  );
    return $items;
}
```

then I created two files, user-login.tpl.php and user-pass.tpl.php
Which each have code like this:

```
<p><?php print render($intro_text); ?></p>
<div class="responsive_bartik-user-login-form-wrapper">
  <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
  <p><a href="password">Forgot Password</a></p>
  <p>Don't have an account? <a href="examplesite.com">Sign Up</a></p>

</div>
```

I tried to the the same thing with the registration form but it still looks the same. It has not overriding it. Here is the code i am used for that:

```
  $items['user_register'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'responsive_bartik') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-register',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
       'responsive_bartik_preprocess_user_register'
    ),
  );
```

I stuck this right before the
 `return $items;
}`
section.

Then i created a file: user-register.tpl.php and placed this code into it:

```
<h1>Hello TEST!</h1>
<p><?php print render($intro_text); ?></p>
<div class="responsive_bartik-user-pass-form-wrapper">
  <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
  <p>Already have an account?<a href="login">Log in</a></p>
  <p>Don't have an account? <a href="http://examplesite.com">Sign Up</a></p>
</div>
```

Form output didn't change.
I am using Profile2 Module and Logintoboggan Module

Answer (score 1):

You need to use user_register_form instead of user_register.

Try using it like this :

```
$items['user_register_form'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'responsive_bartik'). '/templates',
    'template' => 'templates/user-register-form',
    'preprocess functions' => array('responsive_bartik_preprocess_user_register'),
);
```

Now create a user-register-form.tpl.php in your themes template folder.

Comment: Thanks! this worked. I now need to figure out how to find the individual names of my fields to render them in the form. Any hints how to find the way to print render the Address fields from the location module? Specifically one field in the address group, postal code?

Comment: If you are using Profile2 module you can render them using  `<?php print render($form['profile_consumer']['field_first_name']);?>`.  Here profile_consumer should be the profile name you created.  For Account fields you can render them like this `<?php print render($form['account']['name']);?>`

Comment: and if i created custom fields within the account (not profile2) i would add them by replacing 'name' with the machine name of that field? such as 'field_first_name' for the new field labelled first name? I attempted print render($form['account']['field_first_name']); with no luck

Comment: Yes whatever Profile2 fields that you have created can be accessed in this tpl file. Try printing the entire array and you will find your fields inside. Traverse them and have them rendered.

Comment: Ok Final Question. How do I get the error messages and such to print, I tried <?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?> But this reprints all fields that i dont want. it seems to show the full form again.

Comment: You need to add this code at the end. I think the error messages should appear as usual. `print render($form["form_build_id"]);
print drupal_render($form['form_token']);
print drupal_render($form['form_id']);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) to edit it.

Try adding this to your custom module:

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_register_form':
    //put your code here
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a way to add specific fields that are within a field group? Example is the Location Module. I would like to only add the Postal Code field to the form, but it is within the whole group. How would that look like in my tpl.php file?

Comment: You first need to unset your Postal Code field, `unset($form['field_postal_code`, then just render your field, to display only this one.